# ArgumentError: parent directory is world writable, FileUtils#remove_entry_secure does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, production-environment

I try to deploy the Rails app to the server. But I got this error when the webpage runs. I did a lot of research on this problem, and most of them are to change the permission. But i absolutely can not change the permission in .socket folder. If anyone knows how to fix this problem, please help me out. Thanks

```
parent directory is world writable, FileUtils#remove_entry_secure does not work; abort: "/.socket/fcgi/passenger-native-support-d8m77l" (parent directory mode 40777) (ArgumentError)
  /.socket/ruby/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:716:in `remove_entry_secure'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb:72:in `ensure in mktmpdir'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb:72:in `mktmpdir'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:147:in `download_binary_and_load'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:49:in `start'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:405:in `<top (required)>'
  /.socket/ruby/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /.socket/ruby/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /.socket/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger.rb:237:in `require_passenger_lib'
  /.socket/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:75:in `init_passenger'
  /.socket/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
  /.socket/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /.socket/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue with Passenger. Try this `chmod o+t -R /tmp`

Read more about the sticky bit here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp

Comment: I saw this solution a lot. the problem is the error does not point out to tmp folder, and also I do not have permission to change this folder.

Comment: That's too bad, because the fix to this known problem requires being able to change permissions. There's more here about this issue: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1292. I hope you find a way to get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `sudo chmod o-w tmp/` worked for me
This removes world writable permissions for the directory